# Is there always a new line character (\n) in the end of every file?

Tags: c++, input, stream, character, newline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inStream("input.txt");
    char next;
    inStream.get(next);
    while(! inStream.eof( ))
    {
        cout << (int) next << " ";
        inStream.get(next);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

file "input.txt":

```
ab
c
```

In theory, there are exactly four character 'a', 'b', '\n', 'c' ( I typed them by myself )

But in fact, the output of the above-mentioned program is : 'a', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\n'.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: NO. There will be no newline `\n` in file if you do not put it there.

Comment: Thank you for you help but I still cannot understand why my output ends in '\n'. Meanwhile, the input file "input.txt" has exactly four character 'a', 'b', '\n' and 'c' ( I typed them by myself)

Comment: End of file is EOF macro which is negative integral value.

Comment: @DivyangPatel Thank you very much. However, I don't mean that. I just wonder why '\n' can be automatically appended to file "input.txt"?

Comment: @MrCold It can't be. You must have entered it. Check your input.txt file with text editor which show CRLF characters

Answer (score 1):

I assume You are editing input.txt in linux and most linux editors appaend LF character at end of last line.

Windows uses CRLF (\r\n, 0D 0A) line endings while Linux/Unix just uses LF (\n, 0A).

If you do not want this to happen , edit file on windows and copy file to linux and execute same without changing any code.
I executed code with both ways and got below output.

When `input.txt`  is edited on Linux.
`97 98 10 99 10`

When `input.txt`  is edited on Windows and copied to Linux.
`97 98 13 10 99`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no guarantee a file ends in `\n` - or any character, even the ASCII `EOF` character (which makes no sense to me). A file is just a stream of arbitrary bytes. You can have zero-byte files, 1-byte, 2-byte, and so on with nothing certain about what those bytes are.

Often files DO end in `\n` because they're written in a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfLines;i++) {

    fs << getSomeText( i ) << endl;
}
fs.close();
```

Note the `endl`, which will cause every line, including the last line, to end with `\n`.

Of course, on Windows it's `\r\n` and old-school (pre-OS X) Mac OS it's `\r`, just to be awkward.

Comment: Thank you for you help !

I understand your example but that is not what I mean.

In my example, there is NO "\n" in the end of my file "input.txt" but the output have it. Could you please explain it for me?

Comment: @user3686310 How do you **know** that input.txt does not end with `\n`?

Comment: I typed it by myself. I typed exactly four characters: 'a', 'b', '\n' (Enter) and 'c'.

Comment: @user3686310 Into what editor? It's possible your editor is automatically appending `\n` at the end. Gedit, Gvim, Vim, Nano etc all end `\n` to the end of files they save by default.

Comment: I use Dev-C++. You are probably right: \n is automatically appended to the file :)